# How to create a generic array with nullable values in kotlin

Tags: arrays, generics, kotlin

Okay, so to try to learn the kotlin language, I am trying to implement a heap.

```
class Heap <T : Comparable<T>>(private var heap: Array<T>, private var size: Int){
```

I am having some difficulties with how the nullable types behave. In the beginning I gave a array of elements, but I started having difficulties when I wanted to allocate more elements

```
private fun increaseSize(){
    if(size == heap.size){
        //okay this is garbage
        var enlargedHeap = arrayOfNulls<Comparable<*>>(heap.size * 2) as Array<T> 
        System.arraycopy(heap, 0, enlargedHeap, 0, size)
        heap = enlargedHeap
    }
}
```

So here I am guessing I am changing the heap from `Array<T>` to `Array<T?>` which makes sense. So I changed the constructor as well, to take `Array<T?>` and it suggests some pretty interesting things wherever I try to access `heap[x]`

```
else heap[pos1].compareTo(heap[pos2]) < 0
```

to

```
else heap[pos2]?.let { heap[pos1]?.compareTo(it) }!! < 0
```

then I looked at a tooltip stating that `arrayOfNulls<Comparable<*>>(heap.size * 2) as Array<T>` returned `Array<T>`

But when doing the `arrayOfNulls` it indeed returns an array with null values. However I get an error if I try to `heap[x] = null`

stating

> Null cannot be a value of non-null type T

If I change the constructor to take a `Array<T?>`, then input arrays have to explicitly nullable too.

Which I fixed with

```
class Heap <T : Comparable<T>>{

private var heap: Array<T?>
private var size = 0

constructor(heap: Array<T>, size){
    this.heap = heap as Array<T?>
    this.size = size
}
```

But now it does not accept arrays that has null values when I try to instantiate it with an array with nullable values

```
var arr = arrayOfNulls<String>(9)
var heap = Heap(arr, arr.size-1)
```

So now I need two constructors? What is going on

> Type mismatch. Required: Comparable Found:String?

Even with `Àrray<T?>` there is errors with the compareTo's not accepting nullable values.

Even with checks it still gives an error

```
return  if(pos2 > size || (heap[pos1] == null || heap[pos2] == null)) false
        else heap[pos1].compareTo(heap[pos2]) < 0
```

> Type mismatch. Required:T Found: T?

How do I allow the array to contain null values?

Hopefully without making `Array<T>` nullable since it breaks the compareTo's and multiple constructors seems like bad design.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are tricky to work with in a generic class because they have reified types.

I think you need to move the backing array property out of the constructor so the constructor won't be ambiguous about nullability. Otherwise type inference won't work with the constructor, and you would also be forced to use a nullable-typed array as the constructor parameter even if you want the heap to have a non-nullable type. Anyway, it's good that you copy the array from the constructor rather than using it directly as a backing array, because otherwise there is the possibility that some outside object could still be modifying that backing array.

Since Arrays always have reified type, I think you also need to use a backing array of type `Any?`. This will mean you have to cast objects that are passed out of the heap in the public functions. You can make a single get function for that, and use it internally with `this[]` to avoid having to put casts all over your class. The unchecked casting is safe as long as you don't put anything besides a `T` in the part of the array below `size`, and you don't try to get values above `size`, since they're always null and `T` might not be nullable.

```
class Heap <T : Comparable<T>>(initialValues: Array<T>, private var size: Int) {
    init {
        if (size > initialValues.size) 
            error("Initial array is too small for initial size.")
    }
    private var heap = Array<Any?>(size){ initialValues[it] }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    private operator fun get(index: Int) = heap[index] as T

    private fun increaseSize(){
        var enlargedHeap = arrayOfNulls<Any>(heap.size * 2)
        System.arraycopy(heap, 0, enlargedHeap, 0, size)
        heap = enlargedHeap
    }

    fun pop(): T {
        if (size == 0)
            error("Cannot pop when size is 0")
        size--
        val out = this[size] // Use this class's getter to avoid having to cast
        heap[size] = null
        return out
    }

    fun push(value: T) {
        if (size == heap.size)
            increaseSize()
        heap[size] = value
        size++
    }

}
```

You might also consider moving the size parameter out of the constructor to make usage simpler and avoid the ambiguous case of what happens if the input `size` is smaller than the array you pass in.

```
class Heap <T : Comparable<T>>(initialValues: Array<T>) {
    private var size = initialValues.size
    private var heap = Array<Any?>(size){ initialValues[it] }
    //...
```

Comment: Somehow I cannot use compareTo with the Any type? Which is a big issue because I use ADT's implementing the interface in the heap

Comment: I don't know what ADT is. But if you want to do a comparison, cast the values first. Which is what the `get` function above does for you.

Comment: You can't cast arrays to use different types because they use reified types. You'll get a ClassCastException. And if you just make your backing array an `Array <Comparable<*>?>`, you will still have to cast what you get out of the array because of the star projection.

Comment: I don't know what your comparisons are being used for, but if you use the getter that casts, it just works: `fun secondMoreThanFirst(): Boolean = this[1] > this[0]`

Comment: How should I convert the elements from Any? back to T?

Comment: See the `get()` function in my code? It just casts them to T. So if you use `this[i]` instead of `heap[i]`, you get a T instead of an Any?.

Comment: Yeah, I mean how do I convert Array<Any?> to Array<T>

Comment: You can't. Arrays are invariant. You cannot possibly create an `Array<T>` unless `T` is a reified parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `Array<T?>`, instead of `Array<T>`.

E.g. in your class signature, properties should be:

`class Heap <T : Comparable<T>>(private var heap: Array<T?>, private var size: Int) {`

If you need input with not null values, please use something like this:

```
     private var heap = initialHeap.toArray(); // copy input parameter to internal array
```